# Chamar um v-on por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, opencart

Bom pessoal, tenho um form que utiliza Vue, onde toda vez que eu escrevo alguma coisa ele faz um requisição no backend para salvar os dados com o `v-on:change` e quando saio do campo ele faz a mesma coisa com o `v-on:blur`
Estou utilizando OpenCart e não tenho como fazer de outra maneira, então preciso do seguinte.

Tenho meu campo CEP que faço requisição no viacep e preencho os dados dos outros campos (endereço, bairro, cidade, estado) e após isso eu foco no campo do número. Porém quando saio do input número ele reseta os campos que eu preenchi sem passar por eles.

Como eu faria para conseguir mandar o `v-on:change` e `v-on:blur` através do JavaScript?

Meus códigos abaixo:

```
Requisição após sair do campo CEP
$("#input-payment-postcode").focusout(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+$(this).val()+'/json/unicode/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
          $("#input-payment-address-1").val(response.logradouro);
          $("#input-payment-address-2").val(response.bairro);
          $("#input-payment-city").val(response.localidade);

          switch (response.uf) { // apaguei os outros case para diminuir o tamanho
            case 'AC':
              $("#input-payment-zone").val(440);
              break;
          }

          $("#input-payment-custom-field3").focus(); // campo número
        }
      });
    });
```

Exemplo do meu input CEP, os outros cheguem a mesma forma

```
<input tabindex='9' v-model.lazy="order_data.{{ type }}_postcode" v-on:blur="checkSave()" v-on:change="change()" type="text" name="postcode" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_postcode }}" id="input-{{ type }}-postcode" class="form-control"/>
```

No arquivo que faz envia para o backend por Vue, tem as seguintes funções `change()` e `chekcSave()`; onde o checkSave chama o `save` e salva os dados no backend e depois chama o `update` para mandar os dados nos campos novamente.

```
change: function () {
            this.$data.changed = true;
        },
        changeAddressType: function (type, value) {
            if (value === 'new') {
                this.$data.order_data[type + '_address_id'] = '';
            } else {
                this.$data.order_data[type + '_address_id'] = this.default_address_id;
            }
        },
        checkSave: function (confirm) {
            if (this.$data.changed === true) {
                this.$data.changed = false;

                this.save(confirm);
            }
        },
        save: function (confirm) {
            this.error = {};

            this.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=journal3/checkout/save' + (confirm ? '&confirm=true' : ''),
                data: {
                    account: this.account,
                    order_data: this.order_data,
                    password: this.password,
                    privacy: this.privacy,
                    agree: this.agree,
                    payment_address_type: this.payment_address_type,
                    shipping_address_type: this.shipping_address_type,
                    coupon: this.coupon,
                    voucher: this.voucher
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    this.update(json, confirm);
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },
        update: function (json, confirm) {
            if (json.response.redirect) {
                window.location = json.response.redirect;
            } else {
                this.totals = json.response.totals;
                this.products = json.response.products;
                this.vouchers = json.response.vouchers;
                this.data.total = json.response.total;
                this.session = json.response.session;
                this.error = json.response.error;

                $('#cart-total').html(json.response.total);
                $('.cart-content > ul').html($(json.response.cart).find('.cart-content > ul').html());
                $('#cart-items.count-badge').html(json.response.total_items);

                if (json.response.error) {
                    $('#quick-checkout-button-confirm').button('reset');

                    try {
                        console.error(JSON.stringify(json.response.error, null, 2));
                    } catch (e) {
                    }

                    if (json.response.error.payment_code) {
                        alert(json.response.error.payment_code);
                    }

                    if (json.response.error.shipping_code) {
                        alert(json.response.error.shipping_code);
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        try {
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.form-group .text-danger').closest('.form-group').offset().top - 50 }, 'slow');
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    }, 300);
                } else {
                    if (confirm) {
                        var btns = ['input[type="button"]', 'input[type="submit"]', 'button[type="submit"]', '#button-confirm', '.buttons a'];
                        var $btn = $('.quick-checkout-payment').find(btns.join(', ')).first();

                        if ($btn.attr('href')) {
                            window.location = $btn.attr('href');
                        } else {
                            $btn.trigger('click');
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.payment();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Quando ele retorna do `update` ele reseta os campos que eu 'não modifiquei' entrando neles em si, pois eu setei através do jQuery.
Como eu faria para mandar esses dados através do JavaScript ou jQuery?

Coloquei o código completo no pastebin: https://pastebin.com/8vcxrwNG

Comment: Já tentou disparar o evento `blur`: jQuery -> `$('#el').trigger('blur')` ou Vanilla -> `document.querySelector('#el').dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'))` ?

Comment: Evita usar jQuery com Vue... o que precisas fazer com Vue se pensares num cenário sem jQuery?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr já tinha tentando usar isso, mas não funciona

Comment: @Sergio Pode ser sem jQuery, problema que os inputs são dinâmicos e estão em outro arquivo, quando eu passo input por input funciona normalmente. Problema é que preciso enviar os v-on através do javascript sem entrar no campo deles.

Comment: Estou adaptando um tema de opencart e nesta parte do tema ele utiliza Vue para fazer esse serviço, mas nunca utilizei Vue e não entendo muito bem como funciona para fazer dessa isso

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"os inputs são dinâmicos e estão em outro arquivo"_  e _"preciso enviar os v-on através do javascript sem entrar no campo deles"_?

Comment: os campos do formulário estão em um arquivo address.twig, aonde tem todos os campos(os padrões do opencart e os customizados) aonde não é possível editar com js esse arquivo. aonde posso edita-lo é o arquivo checkout.twig pois o address.twig é carregado nele. Aonde está montado o arquivo com vue é o checkout.js. Não sei como eu faria para acessar eles

Comment: @Sergio A página de finalização de compras do *OpenCart* tem vários passos para a conclusão da compra (Registro, Endereço de Entrega, Endereço de Pagamento etc). Cada vez que o usuário clica em "continuar", a plataforma envia uma requisição para uma rota (ex: `checkout/payment_method`), que retorna um *HTML* daquele passo e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @AndreLacomski Se possível posta o código completo no [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) e posta o *link* aqui.

Comment: Segue o link do pastebin: https://pastebin.com/8vcxrwNG
Postei na pergunta também

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira.

Meu objeto Vue foi atribuído a `windows['_QuickCheckout']`, sendo assim eu chamo ele no meu arquivo  `checkout.twig` e atribuo os valores necessários, sem precisar utilizar o `v-on:change` e `v-on:blur` da seguinte maneira.

```
window['_QuickCheckoutData'].order_data.payment_address_1 = response.logradouro;
window['_QuickCheckoutData'].order_data.payment_address_2 = response.bairro;
window['_QuickCheckoutData'].order_data.payment_city = response.localidade;
```

Estava tentando fazer de uma maneira mais difícil, sendo que já estava pronto para uso.